# Как получить координаты мыши в Xlib и перевести их в OpenGL координаты

Tags: c++, opengl, x11, xlib, координаты

Как получить координаты мыши в Xlib (**относительно окна, не учитывая его координаты**) и перевести их в 2D OpenGL координаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам очевидно нужно использовать вызвов:

```
Bool XQueryPointer(Display *display, Window w, Window *root_return, Window *child_return, int *root_x_return, int *root_y_return, int *win_x_return, int *win_y_return, unsigned int *mask_return);
```

указав идентификатор дочернего окна, [чтобы получить координаты курсора](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html).

Затем вызов:

```
Status XGetWindowAttributes(Display *display, Window w, XWindowAttributes *window_attributes_return);
```

[чтобы получить размеры окна](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html).

После чего разделить первое на второе и использовать обычное линейной преобразование координат. Умножить на два и сдвинуть влево на половину экрана(отнять единицу)

OpenGL:

```
(-1,1)(1,1)
(-1,-1)(1,-1)
```

xlib:

```
(0,0)     (640,0) 
(0,480) (640,480)
```

Например для окна размером 640*480 хотим преобразовать координату 100,100:

```
x: 100*2/640 - 1 = -0.6875
y: -(100*2/480 -1) = 0.5833
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно преобразовать не зависимо от того, как строится система координат. Сейчас, например, они начинаются в нижнем левом углу.

Comment: @reload Преобразовывать координаты вне зависимости от конкретной системы координат? Вы я вижу оригинал и перфекционист. Только вот что вы будете в таком случае делать с тем фактом что в качестве системы координат теоретически может быть использовано вообще любое множество из континуума? P.S. Чтобы обойти эти суровые реалии конкретную систему координат обычно выбирает разработчик на стадии написании спецификации и далее все пользователи её придерживаются. Они там никогда не меняются. В OpenGL (1,1) будет всегда справа вверху, а в X (0,0) слева вверху.